# How to ensure database auto-creation with entity framework 7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

What is the best way to ensure the database is auto created (if it doesn't exist) with EF7?  I read that you aren't supposed to put `Database.EnsureCreated` in your 
`DatabaseContext` constructor so not sure how to properly wire this up.

Here is the `ConfigureService` method for the OdeToFood/Startup.cs class (asp.net core 1.0.1 web app):

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
    services.AddSingleton<IGreeter, Greeter>();
    services.AddScoped<IRestaurantData, SqlRestaurantData>();
    services.AddDbContext<OdeToFoodDbContext>(options => 
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("OdeToFood")));
    services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<OdeToFoodDbContext>();
}

public class OdeToFoodDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public OdeToFoodDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Found one way to do it.  Not sure if it's the best way to do it.     `public class OdeToFoodDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {

        public OdeToFoodDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: Are you using EFC its not called EF7, secondly you would probably want the "Migrations" feature which was also part of EF6.    `_context.Database.Migrate()` (async version available also).

Comment: Keep in mind that `Database.EnsureCreated()` doesn't take migrations into account.